# MPChart Android Lable

Tags: android, bar-chart

First of all I should apologize for my poor English.

I have written a piece of code to present some data in horizontal bar chart. To do that, I have used android MPChart library Version 3. But I want to show every bar name, in left side of that bar.

The problem is that in the code that I have written, the names are not placed correctly. ( I want to show the name of each bar EXACTLY in front of that bar but as you can see in the picture the labels are not in their place and also the label "Item 1" is repeated that I don’t know what is the reason)

Here is the code :

```
public class HorizontalBarchartActivity extends Activity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

protected HorizontalBarChart mChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mChart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    BarData data = new BarData();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(i - 1, i * 10));

        BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Item" + i);
        dataSet.setColor(generateRadomColor());
        data.addDataSet(dataSet);
    }

    String[] labels = new String[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        labels[i] = "Item " + (i + 1);
    }

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(12, true);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(labels));


    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.setFitBars(true);
    mChart.animateY(2500);
    mChart.invalidate();

}

private int generateRadomColor() {
    // Generate the random integers for r, g and b value
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(255);
    int g = rand.nextInt(255);
    int b = rand.nextInt(255);
    return Color.rgb(r, g, b);
}

protected RectF mOnValueSelectedRectF = new RectF();

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

    if (e == null)
        return;

    RectF bounds = mOnValueSelectedRectF;
    mChart.getBarBounds((BarEntry) e, bounds);

    MPPointF position = mChart.getPosition(e, mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(h.getDataSetIndex())
            .getAxisDependency());

    Log.i("bounds", bounds.toString());
    Log.i("position", position.toString());

    Toast.makeText(this, e.getY() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    MPPointF.recycleInstance(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
}

private class LabelFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    private final String[] mLabels;

    LabelFormatter(String[] labels) {
        mLabels = labels;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        if (mLabels != null && mLabels.length > (int) value) {
            return mLabels[(int) value];
        } else return "";
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance for your attention

Comment: Might be use are using xAxis.setLabelCount(12, true); 

Replace 12 with 11..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the items count are 12 so labels are also 12.

Answer (score 0):

I used that library a while ago, I remember wanting to modify something about it, you could try

```
        XAxis xAxis = bchSale.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
        //xAxis.setLabelCount(4);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return "Your String";
            }
        });
```

You can revsiar my [repo](https://github.com/RicardoBravoA/ChartDemo), maybe help you